# Application Architecture Suggestion

Tags: java, architecture, java-me

I am preparing a J2ME application,
Which is basically data capturing utility, Which reads data from end user from form and the data will be submitted to server as the application will get connection.

I am planning to capture photo also.

Now my arch. is MIDlet will fetch data from user and will store it in RMS and as the connection is available the data will be submitted to server and it will be removed locally.

The main question is is it reliable to use RMS to store data.
My one data entry will be something like + a photo[optional]

```
"asdjbdabhsdfjkbahsdkfbakjsdfhasfjasdfhjasdlcjalmsdhfjasdfajksdlmcfjkanmsdfgsahjkcnfhs"
```

suggest me arch. changes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really struggling to understand your question.

if your asking if RMS is a reliable storage method for pictures the answer is yes. 
You just have to convert your image to a byte array and save. Then when you need to make it back into an image, the Image class has a constructor for making a new Image from byte array anyway. The RMS is persistent so your data will be there if you stop the app and as a default your applications RMS should only be accessible to your application (although I think you can change this manually).

I'm currently developing a peace of software witch stores pictures, audio recordings and ID strings as well as date and time stamps on the phone it's self prior to a server upload point and I use the RMS.

I'm not actually sure if there's any other form of local storage that J2ME has access to.

Comment: ya but there is certain limit to RMS we need to consider it also.

Comment: define limit, as in total size you can save? "The amount of memory available for record-based data storage varies from device to device." (http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/databaserms/). if it's this then it would depend what phone you have. I think you can check with RecordStore.getSizeAvailable();